# Limit images returned less than 20 Instagram API

Tags: instagram

I have a small script a friend has helped me with. I only want to return 10 images from the API. Here is a link to my [instagram api example](https://github.com/mxpimp47/apiexample/blob/master/instagram.html) using the featured images from instagram.

As I mentioned someone has helped me put this together, I am not very advanced so figuring it out on my own is difficult. I have searched stackoverflow, and google. But most posts want to display more than the 20 limit.

If anyone has some links to where I can read up on this, I would be glad to do so!

Thanks, Clayton

Comment: You should specify what specifically you are trying to 'figure out', what you tried including code, and what did not work.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to control the images returned. 20 is the default and only wanted to return 10. Sorry if my question was a bit vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `count` parameter. Change this line:

```js
var apiUrl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=" + client_id + "&callback=?"
```

To:

```js
var apiUrl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=" + client_id + "&callback=?&count=10"
```

Comment: I looked up the count param in javascript, I knew I was in headed in the right direction. But I couldnt figure where to put it exactly. Thank you for the help!

Comment: For some reason it is only returning 7 images. I dont know why it would do that.

Comment: did you see whats happening with the count? They say the default is 20, so it should work right?