# How to get more than 20 posts from instagram using their API?. I had used count property also. Eventhough, API is returning 20 posts only

Tags: instagram-api

How to get more than 20 posts from Instagram using their API?. I had used count property also. Even-though, API is returning 20 posts only.

Answer (score 0):

Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815839/limit-images-returned-less-than-20-instagram-api) for changing a count parameter that looks like so:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=34.048502&lng=-118.246008&distance=5000&access_token=1771051239.ab103e5.7e013b99ce924cb7a894ecd0dd030be5&callback=?&count=100
```

looks like 100 is as high as you can go

good luck

Comment: Hi Rick, Thanks for the reply. I got annwer for it. If we created the Client in sandbox mode, we will recieve max 20 posts for all the instagram request.

Comment: So to receive all the posts, need to move our client to GoLive mode